# Aggregate (Mean) of a resulting visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having a problem since I want an aggregated version of a filtered resulting visual. 

Process:

1. Using a Text Filter: 
   a. Input Merchant ID and Year-Month.

- Resulting Visual 1 will look like this if you input Merchant ID (1234) and Year-Month (2020-01):

```
Merchant ID    CardNum    Year-Month   Amount
   1234         1abc1      2020-01      1.00
   1234         2def2      2020-01      100.00
   1234         3ghi3      2020-01      65.00
```

2. Visual 2 then displays the Merchant History for each CardNumber listed in Visual 1.

- Resulting Visual 2 will look like this:

```
Card Number    Merchant ID  Date          Amount
   1abc1         abc        2020-01        1.00
   1abc1         def        2020-01        2.00
   1abc1         xyz        2020-01        3.00
   2def2         abc        2020-01       100.00
   2def2         xyz        2020-01       200.00
   3ghi3         abc        2020-01       300.00
```

**Now I want something that will give me this output ordered from highest to lowest:**

```
Merchant ID  xRatio
abc            1
xyz           2/3
def           1/3
```

*xRatio is the mean of Merchant ID occurrences aggregated over the card numbers*

**Detailed Explanation:**
Merchant ID abc occurred for all 3 card numbers thus ((1+1+1)/3) is the result 
Merchant ID xyz occurred for 2 card numbers thus ((1+1)/3) is the result 
Merchant ID def occurred for 1 card number only thus (1/3) is the result

*where "n" is the count of unique card numbers as seen in Visual 1*

Comment: for your last output, which set of data is input here?

Comment: @mkRabbani It should automatically be derived from Visual 2's data. There will be no output. Is that possible in power BI?

Comment: So, output of visual 2 is the input of visual 3 - right?

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this following 3 measure and 1 custom column in given order in your table-

**1.**

```
distinct_card_number = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[Card Number]),
    ALL(your_table_name)
)
```

**2.** Create a **custom column** as below

```
card-merchant = your_table_name[Card Number] & "-" & your_table_name[Merchant ID]
```

**3.**

```
distinct_merchant_count = DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[card-merchant])
```

**4.** now create the final measure as below-

```
xRatio = 
IF(
    [distinct_card_number] = [distinct_merchant_count],
    "1",
    [distinct_merchant_count] &"/"& [distinct_card_number]
```

)

Now add merchant_id and xRatio to your table visual. The output will be like below-

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219979/discussion-on-answer-by-mkrabbani-aggregate-mean-of-a-resulting-visual-in-powe).